# Error when using web3.js with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, web3js

When I run the following Jest test which uses the [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) package

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

test("Web3 version", function()
{
    expect(Web3.version).toEqual("1.0.0-beta.23");
});
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot find module './build/Release/scrypt' from 'index.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)
```

web3 appears to be installed correctly as the following correctly outputs `Web3 version = 1.0.0-beta.23`

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

console.log("Web3 version = " + Web3.version);
```

I'm new to Jest (used it for the first time today) so I'm not sure if the problem is my Jest installation/setup or web3.js.

I've created a simple project on GitHub to replicate the problem
https://github.com/naddison36/web3-jest

My machine is running Mac OS X `10.12.6`, node `v6.10.3` and npm `3.10.10`.
The test project is using web3.js version `1.0.0-beta.23` and Jest `21.2.1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your *package.json* add "node" to *jest -> moduleFileExtensions* should fix it.

> `{...
>   "jest": {
>       "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
>       "moduleFileExtensions": [
>         "ts",
>         "tsx",
>         "js",
>         "jsx",
>         "json",
>         "node"
>       ]
>     }
>   }`

reference: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulefileextensions-array-string

Comment: Thank you. Adding "node" to the "moduleFileExtensions" did the trick!

Comment: @naddison if you find it useful, could you add the answer as the accepted answer? ;)

Comment: @Ronin let me know how I can help. If you can provide some more details.

Comment: doesn't work for me, here's the error: `These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • testRegex
  • moduleFileExtensions`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, change this line require("./build/Release/scrypt") to require("scrypt") from '/node_modules/scrypt/index.js'